# Why does Git think my cs file is binary?

Tags: git, github, binary

I have just one cs file in my repository which Git seems to think is binary. (In `git gui`, it just says "binary files differ".)

How can I indicate to Git that my cs file is a text file?

Comment: If you're in Windows, git may be interpreting Unicode as binary.  It has been doing that for me.

Comment: Recent git has working-tree-encoding for this. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145687/why-does-git-think-my-sql-file-is-a-binary-file/54671781

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try and set your cs files as text in a `.gitattributes` file.

```
*.vmc diff
```

(as described in the [`.gitattributes` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html))
or try to diff them as text (`git diff --text`)

But if your .cs files are UTF-8 or UTF-16, this [can be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778291/how-do-i-diff-utf-16-files-with-gnu-diff/778315#778315), unless you set your `diff` to use an [external tool able to handle those encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text/1300928#1300928).

Comment: Thanks for answering, as it happens I will never know. I just created a new file and copied the contents from one to the other, and it started working again. Strange...

Comment: Works great for `UTF-8` MS SQL Server `.sql` files, too. i.e. `*.sql diff`.