# Why does Git treat this text file as a binary file?

Tags: git, binary

I wonder why git tells me this?

```
$ git diff MyFile.txt
diff --git a/MyFile.txt b/MyFile.txt
index d41a4f3..15dcfa2 100644
Binary files a/MyFile.txt and b/MyFile.txt differ
```

Aren't they text files?

I have checked the `.gitattributes` and it is empty. Why I am getting this message ?, I cannot get diffs as I use to anymore

**ADDED :**

I've noticed there is an `@` in the file permissions, what is this ?, Could this be the reason ?

```
$ls -all
drwxr-xr-x   5 nacho4d  staff    170 28 Jul 17:07 .
drwxr-xr-x  16 nacho4d  staff    544 28 Jul 16:39 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 nacho4d  staff   6148 28 Jul 16:15 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--@  1 nacho4d  staff    746 28 Jul 17:07 MyFile.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 nacho4d  staff  22538  5 Apr 16:18 OtherFile.txt
```

Comment: It could be a UTF-8 encoded file.

Comment: It is supposed to be UTF16 little endian LF

Comment: From the `ls` manpage on Mac OS X: *If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the `-l` option is followed by a `@` character*.  Use option `-@` to see these extended attributes.

Comment: I think this could be a bug of git. I deleted the extended attributes and now everything is fine again.

Comment: @Marnix: UTF-8 encoded file will be detected as text. UTF-16 encoded file on the other hand is binary.

Comment: @nacho4d: That's strange, because git shouldn't even know that there are any extended attributes. If you could reproduce it, it would be worth bringing up on the git mailing list. As is good custom on `vger.kernel.org` lists, you do not have to subscribe to post (people will keep you CC'ed for answers) and are kind of supposed not to given the rather high volume of the `git@vger.kernel.org` list.

Comment: @nacho4d please post `hexdump MyFile.txt`.

Comment: The general question for all version control engines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110750/how-do-popular-source-control-systems-differentiate-binary-files-from-text-files/7112964#7112964

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does git think my cs file is binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506041/why-does-git-think-my-cs-file-is-binary)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It simply means that when git inspects the actual content of the file (it doesn't *know* that any given extension is not a binary file - you can use the attributes file if you want to tell it explicitly - see the man pages).

Having inspected the file's contents it has seen stuff that isn't in basic ascii characters. Being UTF16 I expect that it will have 'funny' characters so it thinks it's binary.

There are ways of telling git if you have internationalisation (i18n) or extended character formats for the file. I'm not sufficiently up on the exact method for setting that - you may need to RT[Full]M ;-)

Edit: a quick search of SO found [can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text) which should give you a few clues.

Comment: You are almost but not completely not wrong. Git did have inspected the actual files and have seen 'funny' characters there. However it does not "think" UTF-16 is binary. It *is* binary, because text is defined as ASCII-based (that's the only thing the built-in diff will give usable results for) and UTF-16 is not. Yes, there is a way to tell git to use special diff for pattern defined files (using `.gitattributes`).

Comment: I should add, that 'funny characters' really means zero bytes.

Comment: We are both right, but from different perspectives. We both say "Git inspects the contents to determine its type." We both say that to make git know it should be treated as UTF16 the user needs to tell git via `.gitattributes` etc.

Comment: I said you are almost right. The only difference is that I disagree with saying it "thinks" UTF-16 is binary and insist that it "is" binary (because of what "text" means to git).

Comment: @JanHudec: In your view, ALL files are binary.

Comment: @stolsvik, no, in my view, "text is defined as ASCII-based". Because that's what it means in Git.

Comment: @stolosvik, (and JanH) It's a more subtle middle ground in that UTF-8 includes both the base 0-127 ASCII characters, and all other Unicode chars, without need of a null (00h) byte for anything other than the nul char (the 'C' string terminator). Thus Git's text definition is that the content (well the first 1k bytes) should not have a null byte when utf-8 encoded. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16 for a fun read.  My original comment refers to the case when UTF-16 encoded data is viewed as byte pairs, so the high byte for ascii code points will be 00.

Comment: Remember that the `.gitattributes` file itself has to be readable by `git` (so, no UTF-16 encoding and the like)

Comment: TIL: `echo '' > some-file.txt` creates a file with UCS-2 LE BOM encoding (Windows Powershell / Notepad++).... unless you [change the default setting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40098771/358006)

Comment: @JanHudec `\x00` is ASCII

Comment: @CervEd, but it isn't text, because C uses it as terminator for text.

Comment: Unless you're forced to, on windows you should be using [Powershell 7 Pwsh.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.3) --- You can run both Pwsh and WinPS side by side.  That's because `>` in `WinPs` implicitly calls `out-file`, instead of `set-content`. If you're forced to use `WinPS`, make sure you're set up right: [about_CharacterEncoding  PS7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.3) -- how to fix `WinPS`. --

Answer (score 55):

If you have not set the type of a file, Git tries to determine it automatically and a file with really long lines and maybe some [wide characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) (e.g. Unicode) is treated as binary. With the [.gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file you can define how Git interpretes the file. Setting the *diff* attribute manually lets Git interprete the file content as text and will do an usual diff.

Just add a *.gitattributes* to your repository root folder and set the *diff* attribute to the paths or files. Here's an example:

```
src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/public/js/i18n/* diff
doc/Help/NothingToSay.yml                      diff
*.css                                          diff
```

If you want to check if there are attributes set on a file, you can do that with the help of [git check-attr](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-attr.html)

```
git check-attr --all -- src/my_file.txt
```

Another nice reference about Git attributes could be found [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes).

Comment: This was helpful, but is actually incorrect--the right attribute is `diff`, not `text`. The `text` attribute doesn't tell git to diff using text but instead controls how line endings are handled (normalization to LF). See your link to .gitattributes for more details.

Comment: Thanks @ErikE. I have updated my post according to your comment and the Git documentation.

Comment: Additionally, you can set what sort of diff should be performed. For example, if it's an xml file you can use `diff=xml` instead of just `diff`.

Comment: What is the opposite of check-attr - is there a set-attr?  I originally accidentally saved a file as UTF-16, then commited and pushed it, and now BitBucket sees it as UTF-16, even after re-saving it as UTF-8, commiting and pushing it again.  This basically makes my pull requests impossible to read because reviewers need to click into each individual comment to add review comments.

Answer (score 35):

I was having this issue where Git GUI and SourceTree was treating Java/JS files as binary and thus wouldn’t show a diff.

Creating a file named `attributes` in `.git/info` with following content solved the problem:

```
*.java diff
*.js diff
*.pl diff
*.txt diff
*.ts diff
*.html diff
*.sh diff
*.xml diff
```

If you would like this to apply to all repositories, then you can add the file `attributes` in `$HOME/.config/git/attributes`.

Comment: Also note the `<project-root>/.gitattributes` file, which makes the change active for all contributors, and only for the relevant project.

Comment: Adding `* diff` was helpful for me: it shows the difference in all types of files. But your solution is better, because of avoiding showing the unnecessary diff in large binary files.

Comment: Yeah! This helps!

Answer (score 21):

Git will even determine that it is binary if you have one super-long line in your text file. I broke up a long String, turning it into several source code lines, and suddenly the file went from being 'binary' to a text file that I could see (in SmartGit).

So don't keep typing too far to the right without hitting 'Enter' in your editor - otherwise later on Git will think you have created a binary file.

Comment: This is a correct information. I was trying to control diffs to an extremely large MySQL Dump (.sql file), but git treats it as a binary file, even if it has only ASCII/UTF8 data on it. The reason, is that lines are super-long (insert values (one),(two),(three),(...),(3 million...);. Strangely, for every commit, the git repository does not increase by 1.7gb, but only ~350mb. Perhaps, git is compressing the "binary" file before saving it.

Comment: @AlexandreT. Git does indeed compress file blobs (using GZip, IIRC).

Answer (score 16):

I had this same problem after editing one of my files in a new editor.  Turns out the new editor used a different encoding (Unicode) than my old editor (UTF-8).  So I simply told my new editor to save my files with UTF-8 and then git showed my changes properly again and didn't see it as a binary file.

I think the problem was simply that git doesn't know how to compare files of different encoding types. So the encoding type that you use really doesn't matter, as long as it remains consistent.

I didn't test it, but I'm sure if I would have just committed my file with the new Unicode encoding, the next time I made changes to that file it would have shown the changes properly and not detected it as binary, since then it would have been comparing two Unicode encoded files, and not a UTF-8 file to a Unicode file.

You can use an app like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to easily see and change the encoding type of a text file; Open the file in Notepad++ and use the Encoding menu in the toolbar.

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding. It's a charset and UTF-8 is one of its encoding, i.e. the way to encode a Unicode codepoint

Comment: This does not resolve the issue, only avoids it. The issue is that git or its diff tool does not properly recognize text files or does not easily allow the user to override its behaviour.

Answer (score 13):

This is also caused (on Windows at least) by text files that have **UTF-8 with BOM** encoding. Changing the encoding to regular **UTF-8** immediately made Git see the file as type=text

Comment: I have two files that Notepad++ identifies as UTF-8 with BOM encoding. SourceTree/git is identifying one as binary and the other as text. I don't have anything definitive to say except that this doesn't appear to be a completely accurate statement.

Comment: In my case my files were UTF-16 with BOM, changing the encoding with Notepad++ to regular UTF-8 fixed the problem, also I had to add manually in `.gitattributes` file the following: `*.extension diff`

Answer (score 7):

I have had same problem. I found the thread when I search solution on google, still I don't find any clue. But I think I found the reason after studying, the below example will explain clearly my clue.

```
    echo "new text" > new.txt
    git add new.txt
    git commit -m "dummy"
```

for now, the file new.txt is considered as a text file.

```
    echo -e "newer text\000" > new.txt
    git diff
```

you will get this result

```
diff --git a/new.txt b/new.txt
index fa49b07..410428c 100644
Binary files a/new.txt and b/new.txt differ
```

and try this

```
git diff -a
```

you will get below

```
    diff --git a/new.txt b/new.txt
    index fa49b07..9664e3f 100644
    --- a/new.txt
    +++ b/new.txt
    @@ -1 +1 @@
    -new file
    +newer text^@
```

Answer (score 7):

We had this case where an .html file was seen as binary whenever we tried to make changes in it. Very uncool to not see diffs. To be honest, I didn't checked all the solutions here but what worked for us was the following:

1. Removed the file (actually moved it to my Desktop) and commited
   the `git deletion`. Git says `Deleted file with mode 100644 (Regular) Binary file differs`
2. Re-added the file (actually moved
   it from my Desktop back into the project). Git says `New file with mode 100644 (Regular) 1 chunk, 135 insertions, 0 deletions` The file
   is now added as a regular text file

From now on, any changes I made in the file is seen as a regular text diff. You could also squash these commits (1, 2, and 3 being the actual change you make) but I prefer to be able to see in the future what I did. Squashing 1 & 2 will show a binary change.

Comment: Similar with one or two (successfully compiled) cpp files pushed up from VS. Renders the Github gui for _Compare_ ludicrous. One would not wish to be a fly on the bell in such a ding dong interchange,- VS on one side saying it's Github, and on the other side Github saying it's VS. :(

Answer (score 7):

Try using *file* to view the encoding details ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489411/2946116)):

```
cd directory/of/interest
file *
```

It produces useful output like this:

```
$ file *
CR6Series_stats resaved.dat: ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
CR6Series_stats utf8.dat:    UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
CR6Series_stats.dat:         ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
readme.md:                   ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: `file` is not a git command. It's a totally separate tool packaged with git on Windows. Is there documentation showing that this is what git uses for binary file detection?

Comment: Yes `file` is a Linux tool but it's packed with Git in C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin

Answer (score 2):

I had an instance where `.gitignore` contained a double `\r` (carriage return) sequence by purpose.

That file was identified as binary by git. Adding a `.gitattributes` file helped.

```
# .gitattributes file
.gitignore diff
```

Comment: Worked. I also had a double \r to ignore some OS "Icon\r\r" file. Good to know the cause as well as the fix.

Answer (score 2):

If `git check-attr --all -- src/my_file.txt` indicates that your file is flagged as binary, and you haven't set it as binary in `.gitattributes`, check for it in `/.git/info/attributes`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Aux.js to another name, like Sig.js.

The source tree still shows it as a binary file, but you can stage(add) it and commit.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as I pasted some text from a binary Kafka message, which inserted non-visible character and caused git to think the file is binary.

I found the offending characters by searching the file using regex `[^ -~\n\r\t]+`.

- `[` match characters in this set
- `^` match characters not in this set
- `-~` matches all characters from ' ' (space) to '~'
- `\n` newline
- `\r` carriage return
- `\t` tab
- `]` close set
- `+` match one or more of these characters

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message when the files I was diff-ing were generated in the Powershell terminal using the echo command:

```
echo "new file" > newfile.txt
```

The files remained binary even after I have opened and edited them with an editor.

The quick and dirty solution for me was to copy the content of those files, delete them, create them again directly from the editor (not from the terminal), and paste back the contents. Diff-ing afterwards showed the correct per-line conflicts as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent several hours going through everything on this list trying to work out why one of the test projects in my solution wasn't adding any tests to the explorer.

It turned out in my case that somehow (probably due to a poor git merge somewhere) that VS had lost a reference the project altogether. It was still building but I noticed that it only built the dependancies.

I then noticed that it wasn't showing up in the dependencies list itself, so I **removed and re-added the test project** and all my tests showed up finally.

Comment: Visual Studio really isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason my file was showing as binary (an dI was getting no diff using `git diff` or SourceTree) was because the file in question was added as a **Git LFS file**.

Git (and SourceTree) do not seem to be able to diff text files added to LFS. However after a bit of hunting and I was able to fix this by running...
`git config --global diff.lfs.textconv cat`

with help from the suggestion here...
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/440#issuecomment-501007460

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on Windows when using `echo` in Powershell for creating text files.
Using `echo` along with redirection operator `>` to write/append textual data [would produce files with unicode encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.3#character-encoding-in-windows-powershell):

```
PS> echo 'sample' > data.txt
PS> Get-Encoding data.txt

Encoding                    Path
--------                    ----
System.Text.UnicodeEncoding data.txt
```

```
PS> git diff --staged

diff --git a/data.txt b/data.txt
...
Binary files /dev/null and b/data.txt differ
```

One solution is to convert encoding to ASCII: (You can also use [Convert-FileEncoding](https://gist.github.com/jpoehls/2406504) to change the encoding of multiple files all at once)

```
PS> Set-Content data.txt $(Get-Content data.txt) -Encoding ascii
```

This way, git would no longer treat your text files as binaries:

```
PS> git add -A; git diff --staged


diff --git a/data.txt b/data.txt
...
--- /dev/null
+++ b/data.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+sample
```

To avoid this problem in the first place, one should use Powershell `Set-Content` and `Add-Content` commands for creating/appending text files:

```
PS> Set-Content data2.txt 'sample2'
PS> git add -A; git diff --staged data2.txt


diff --git a/data2.txt b/data2.txt
...
--- /dev/null
+++ b/data2.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+sample2
```