# SourceTree Won't Show All My Changes

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I want to commit my works. But when I want to see what I changed and wrote them into commit message, I saw some of my changes won't show.

What is the problem?

Comment: It's possible to get tricked by submodules if you are using them. Let's imagine we have repositories "foo" and "bar". Repository foo contains bar as a submodule. You can now open bar directly or as foo's submodule. Both tabs will be titled "bar". You can determine if you are in a submodule by clicking any file in any commit, choosing "show in explorer" and looking at the path.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Change The Maximum Lines And Size In Options

Tools > Options > Diff

Change Max Diff Line Count
And
Change Size Limit (Text)

Comment: Is possible an unlimited diff?

Comment: I've done exactly this, and the Diff still shows a maximum of 100 lines. applies both in the commit screen, the Log/History screen, and the Log window for that specific file.  This makes it extremely difficult to track changes in files that are only a few hundred lines over a long period. I've set my line maximum to 1,000 and the size limit to 10,000, so this problem shouldn't be happening.

Comment: This does work, but it was necessary for me to close Sourcetree and relaunch it for the change to take effect.

Comment: @aaronsti I thought it wasn't working, but you're right if you relaunch it after the changes it works!

Comment: No reboot necessary in v3.4.12. I wish I could upvote this twice, your answer almost a decade ago saved me from a very painful night

Answer (score 12):

I'm adding this answer as another possible cause of SourceTree "only showing the change history for a single file". This was annoying me for quite a while. No settings changes would display more than one file. THEN, I realised that the commit summary is actually a panel which slides up over the file list. ZOMG.

[image: ZOMG]

Comment: Thanks, this got me too. You have to hover the mouse at the top of the commit summary to see the splitter. Also in my SourceTree v2.2.4 it looks a bit different to your screenshot as the file list has two columns and you can still see the Filename/Path column headers while the commit summary is covering the actual file list.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your filter is setup correctly:

[image]

For me the filter bugged out and while the main text said "Pending files", the dropdown had nothing selected.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason:

Make sure **Ignore whitespace** in the diff view is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

**Size Update For the latest ScourceTree**

```
ScourceTree -> Preferences -> Diff -> Size limit(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I have changed the size limit for the txt file, SourceTree still would not show diff for `package-lock.json`. Instead it shows "**Modified binary file, diff suppressed**". I was confused and looked for the possible answer for that, e.g. [Why does Git treat this text file as a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855712/why-does-git-treat-this-text-file-as-a-binary-file)

[image: package-lock.json]

Then I found there is another setting "**Ignore File pattern**"! After I remove `*lock` pattern, SoureTree finally show the change for `package-lock.json`

[image: ignore lock file]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you copy the last version of your project, the one that you want to commit, to the directory of your repositories that you set for SourceTree. Replace the old project with the new one then open SourceTree
2. Open SourceTree, click commit, select all the files that you want to commit, which will probably be all the files you see (becuase SourceTree shows the changed files after you click commit).
3. On the Puush button on the top you'll se a red notification icon which means that you didn't push the last commit. Once you do that, your changes must be visible on BitBucket and SourceTree

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a Pending issue or an options issue mentioned above, make sure Mercurial wasn't inadvertently checked if you're using it with Git. It will manifest in a similar way. If so, you're going to need to deinstall & re-install.