# Why is .cpp classed as binary file?

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, github

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I'm trying to get my project to work with GitHub. No matter what I do, .cpp file-changes wont show as diff because "Binary files are not shown".

I've tried editing `.gitattributes` file with `*.cpp text` without luck. I've checked and the `.vcxproj` is set to save in UTF-8. I've also tried specifying `eol=lf` but it seems like nothing works. Please help!

Comment: Doesn't windows use CRLF for ending lines?

Comment: Does it help if you add `*.cpp text diff` to `.gitattributes`?

Comment: @JGroven I think so, I thought maybe changing it to something it wasn't would fix it.

Comment: @orhtej2 I did try that and it didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Git treat this text file as a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855712/why-does-git-treat-this-text-file-as-a-binary-file)

Comment: Have you tried using VS to create a trivial file with very little content and see what GitHub thinks about that?

Comment: @user1768788 Have exactly the same issue, and still couldn't resolve it (after reading all the links on SO). Any change you got it fixed?

Answer (score -1):

There might be `.gitignore` file and there may be `*.cpp` which ignore for change on `.cpp` file.

Comment: No, git shows there is a difference, it just doesn't show diff because it treats the files as binary.