# git gui - can it be made to display UTF-16?

Tags: git, diff, utf-16, git-gui

Is there a way to make `git gui` display and show diffs for UTF-16 files somehow?

I found [some information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text), but this is mostly referring to the command line rather than the GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been working on a *much* better solution with help from the msysGit people, and have come up with this clean/smudge filter. The filter uses the Gnu file and iconv commands to determine the type of the file, and convert it to and from msysGit's internal UTF-8 format.

This type of Clean/Smudge Filter gives you much more flexibility. It should allow Git to treat your mixed-format files as UTF-8 text in most cases: diffs, merge, git-grep, as well as gitattributes properties like eol-conversion, ident-replacement, and built-in diff patterns.

The diff filter solution outlined above only works for diffs, and so is much more limited.

To set up this filter:

1. Get Gnu [libiconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm), and [file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm), and install both.
2. Ensure that the GnuWin32\bin directory (usually "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin") is in your %PATH%
3. Add the following to ~\Git\etc\gitconfig:

   ```
   [filter "mixedtext"]
       clean = iconv -sc -f $(file -b --mime-encoding %f) -t utf-8
       smudge = iconv -sc -f utf-8 -t $(file -b --mime-encoding %f)
       required
   ```
4. Add a line to your global ~/Git/etc/gitattributes or local ~/.gitattributes to handle mixed format text, for example:

   ```
   *.txt filter=mixedtext
   ```

I have used this on a directory with sql files in ANSI, UTF-16, and UTF-8 formats. It is working so far. Barring any surprises, this looks like the 20% effort that could cover 80% of all Windows text format problems.

Comment: can you confirm if this solution applies retrospectively for previous commits? I tried this and my edits to UTF-16 files are still not displaying in the `gitk` tool in msysgit.

Comment: this seems to fail when I do a `git pull` that includes files deleted by another git user. I get the error msg from iconv: `conversion to cannot unsupported`... is there anyway to stop this filter from executing on deleted files?

Comment: I've been using this solution for a long time and it works perfectly for msysgit up to 1.9.5 on Windows. In the latest Git 2.x there is no longer a `.gitattributes` file. Do you have a solution that also works in latest Git release?

Answer (score 3):

This method is for MSysGit 1.8.1, and is tested on Windows XP. I use Git Extensions 2.44, but since the changes are at the Git level, they should work for Git Gui as well. Steps:

1. Install [Gnu Iconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm).
2. Create the following script, name it `astextutf16`, and place it in the /bin directory of your Git installation (this is based on the existing `astextplain` script):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -e
   # converts Windows Unicode (UTF-16 / UCS-2) to Git-friendly UTF-8
   # notes:
   # * requires Gnu iconv:
   #       http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm
   # * this script must be placed in: ~/Git/bin
   # * modify global ~/Git/etc/gitconfig or local ~/.git/config:
   #       [diff "astextutf16"]
   #           textconv = astextutf16
   # * or, from command line:
   #       $ git config diff.astextutf16.textconv astextutf16
   # * modify global ~/Git/etc/gitattributes or local ~/.gitattributes:
   #       *.txt diff=astextutf16
   if test "$#" != 1 ; then
       echo "Usage: astextutf16 <file>" 1>&2
       exit 1
   fi
   # -f(rom) utf-16 -t(o) utf-8
   "\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f utf-16 -t utf-8 "$1"
   exit 0
   ```
3. Modify the global ~/Git/etc/gitconfig or your local ~/.git/config file, and add these lines:

   ```
   [diff "astextutf16"]  
       textconv = astextutf16
   ```
4. Or, from command line:

   `$ git config diff.astextutf16.textconv astextutf16`
5. Modify the global ~/Git/etc/gitattributes or your local ~/.gitattributes file, and map your extensions to be converted:

   `*.txt diff=astextutf16`
6. Test. UTF-16 files should now be visible.

Comment: I have made a [9kb replacement for iconv](https://github.com/crea7or/wiconv) (for Windows only) especially for this task

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue.

I would like to improved on the accepted answer, since it has a small flaw. The problem I ran into was that if the file did not exist, I received this error:

> ```
> conversion to cannot unsupported
> ```

I changed the commands so that a file is not required. It uses only [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) and [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29). This fixed the issue. My *.git/config* file now looks like this:

```
[filter "mixedtext"]
    clean = "GITTMP=$(mktemp);TYPE=$( tee $GITTMP|file -b --mime-encoding - ); cat $GITTMP | iconv -sc -f $TYPE -t utf-8; rm -f $GITTMP"
    smudge = "GITTMP=$(mktemp);TYPE=$( tee $GITTMP|file -b --mime-encoding - ); cat $GITTMP | iconv -sc -f utf-8 -t $TYPE; rm -f $GITTMP"
    required = true
```

To create the entries in your *.git/config* file use these commands:

```
git config --replace-all filter.mixedtext.clean 'GITTMP=$(mktemp);TYPE=$( tee $GITTMP|file -b --mime-encoding - ); cat $GITTMP | iconv -sc -f $TYPE -t utf-8; rm -f $GITTMP'
git config --replace-all filter.mixedtext.smudge 'GITTMP=$(mktemp);TYPE=$( tee $GITTMP|file -b --mime-encoding - ); cat $GITTMP | iconv -sc -f utf-8 -t $TYPE; rm -f $GITTMP'
git config --replace-all filter.mixedtext.required true
```

My .gitattributes file looks like this:

```
*.txt filter=mixedtext
*.ps1 filter=mixedtext
*.sql filter=mixedtext
```

Specify only the files that might be an issue otherwise the clean/smudge has to do more work (temp files).

We also bulk converted the [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes) files in Git to UTF-8 since this is the most compact and portable encoding for UTF. The same [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) command used in clean and smudge was perfect for permanently converting the files.

The nice thing about the clean/smudge commands is that even if a file is checked in with, say, UTF-16LE, the diff will still work.