# Can't get git to play nice with iconv and utf-16

Tags: git, utf-16, msysgit, iconv

I'm trying to get git to recognize UTF-16 as text to allow me to diff and patch as text natively, but I'm having trouble getting the `textconv` parameter to work.

I can manually call

```
iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 some-utf-16-file.rc
```

and everything is fine. But if I configure my .gitconfig as follows

```
[diff "utf16"]
    textconv = "iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8"
```

and my .gitattributes:

```
# Custom for MFC
*.rc text eol=crlf diff=utf16
```

However, if I then if I run `git diff`, the following is displayed:

```
iconv: C:/Users/Mahmoud/AppData/Local/Temp/IjLBZ8_OemKey.rc:104:1: incomplete character or shift sequence
```

With procmon I was able to track it down as creating this process:

```
sh -c "iconv.exe -f utf-16le -t utf-8 \"$@\"" "iconv.exe -f utf-16le -t utf-8" C:/Users/Mahmoud/AppData/Local/Temp/JLOkVa_OemKey.rc
```

...which I can actually run fine (on the actual file, though).

Any ideas?

(Please note that I'm aware of the various solutions for getting git to work with UTF-16. I'm specifically trying to address this question of why iconv by itself works but it will not work when called by git. Also, this error was originally encountered while trying one of the linked solutions from the "duplicate" question. Thank you all kindly.)

Comment: Try this: [Can I make git recognize a UTF-16 file as text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text), or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915072/git-gui-can-it-be-made-to-display-utf16

Comment: @paulsm4 My question is actually specifically about getting git and iconv to work nice, not about getting git to work with UTF-16; but thanks!

Comment: Not sure about this - could it have to do with the iconv.exe being binary?

Comment: @Briana I don't think so, sysmon shows it is executed OK.

Comment: Remember - from the DOS/Windows "command line", there's a whole BUNCH of different actors involved: including Cygwin and Windows.  Please read the links I cited: "GNU diff doesn't really care about unicode, so when you use diff --text it just diffs and outputs the text. The problem is that the terminal you're using can't handle the UTF-16 that's emitted (combined with the diff marks that are ASCII characters)."  And please read the *multiple* different workarounds.

Comment: Failing all else, you can always just do everything under Linux :)

Comment: Could it be that git rewrites end-of-line characters (which messes utf-16 up) before giving that file to iconv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use only `diff`, it should work:

```
*.rc diff=utf16
```

`text` and `eol` cause git to substitute end-of-lines before passing data to iconv, after which it is not a valid utf16 anymore, as [noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632428#comment62757388_37632428).

Comment: Thank you for both explaining the cause of the problem and providing a solution to continue using the attempted approach (but correctly). Too bad this can't work with interactive/patch `git add`, but there's no way that it could since there is no guaranteed one-to-one mapping between a filtered view and the source materials.

Answer (score 3):

Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019) adds a new encoding **UTF-16LE-BOM**: invented to force encoding to UTF-16 with BOM in little endian byte order, which cannot be directly generated by using `iconv`.

See [commit aab2a1a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aab2a1ae48ff65781a5379a01a4abb4f75e5641d) (30 Jan 2019) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0fa3cc7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fa3cc77ee9fb3b6bb53c73688c9b7500f996b83), 07 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### Support working-tree-encoding "UTF-16LE-BOM"
>
> Users who want UTF-16 files in the working tree set the `.gitattributes` like this:
>
> ```
> test.txt working-tree-encoding=UTF-16
> ```
>
> The unicode standard itself defines 3 allowed ways how to encode UTF-16.
>   The following 3 versions convert all back to 'g' 'i' 't' in UTF-8:
>
> ```
> a) UTF-16, without BOM, big endian:
> $ printf "\000g\000i\000t" | iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 | od -c
> 0000000    g   i   t
>
> b) UTF-16, with BOM, little endian:
> $ printf "\377\376g\000i\000t\000" | iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 | od -c
> 0000000    g   i   t
>
> c) UTF-16, with BOM, big endian:
> $ printf "\376\377\000g\000i\000t" | iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 | od -c
> 0000000    g   i   t
> ```
>
> Git uses `libiconv` to convert from UTF-8 in the index into ITF-16 in the
>   working tree.
>   After a checkout, the resulting file has a BOM and is encoded in "UTF-16",
>   in the version (c) above.
>   This is what iconv generates, more details follow below.
>
> `iconv` (and `libiconv`) can generate UTF-16, UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE:
>
> ```
> d) UTF-16
> $ printf 'git' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 | od -c
> 0000000  376 377  \0   g  \0   i  \0   t
>
> e) UTF-16LE
> $ printf 'git' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE | od -c
> 0000000    g  \0   i  \0   t  \0
>
> f)  UTF-16BE
> $ printf 'git' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16BE | od -c
> 0000000   \0   g  \0   i  \0   t
> ```
>
> There is no way to generate version (b) from above in a Git working tree,
>   but that is what some applications need.
>   (All fully unicode aware applications should be able to read all 3 variants,
>   but in practice, we are not there yet).
>
> When producing UTF-16 as an output, `iconv` generates the big endian version
>   with a BOM. (big endian is probably chosen for historical reasons).
>
> `iconv` can produce UTF-16 files with little endianess by using "UTF-16LE"
>   as encoding, and that file does not have a BOM.
>
> Not all users (especially under Windows) are happy with this.
>   Some tools are not fully unicode aware and can only handle version (b).
>
> Today there is no way to produce version (b) with `iconv` (or `libiconv`).
>   Looking into the history of `iconv`, it seems as if version (c) will be used in all future `iconv` versions (for compatibility reasons).
>
> Solve this dilemma and introduce a Git-specific "`UTF-16LE-BOM`".
>   libiconv can not handle the encoding, so Git pick it up, handles the BOM
>   and uses libiconv to convert the rest of the stream. (UTF-16BE-BOM is added for consistency)

Answer (score 1):

git recently has begun to understand encodings ie in effect `iconv` is now to some extent builtin.  See [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) docs, search for `working-tree-encoding`

[Make sure your man page matches since this is quite new!]

If (say) the file is utf-16 without bom on windows machine then add to your gitattributes file

```
some-utf-16-file.rc text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16LE eol=CRLF
```

If utf-16 little endinan (with bom) on *nix make it

```
some-utf-16-file.rc text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16 eol=LF
```

Comment: Thanks for this update! I’m guessing this will work with interactive patch add, so it is very welcome!