# git mars line endings in unicode files

Tags: git

Situation:
We are using GitExtensions (latest version) and have certain Unicode-files like Registry exports (.reg files). The .gitattributes file has an entry like this:

```
*.reg text diff
```

Problem:
Git mars the line ends. When pulling back the file (or doing a diff with current version) I get following unexpected changes:

before:
    0D00 0A00 0D00 0A00

after:
    0D00 0D0A 000D 0D00 0A00

Answer (score 0):

try removing `text` attribute. It is [described](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) to enable the endofline conversion

To get textual diff you can use textconv filter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37632428/2303202)