# Git bash does not show tildes

Tags: git, git-bash

I am using GIT within VScode and I have noticed that when using accents in the comments of the commits, when I show the history with **"git log"** the letters with tilde do not show correctly. Verifying I have noticed that VScode invokes GIT through the path **"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"** and when executing this bash directly, I visualize the error so it is valid that it is not a problem with VSCode. On the other hand, when I use the shortcut that was installed with git which is located in **"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"** I verify that there is no problem in showing the tildes (the comments of the commits with tilde appear well written). Finally use the GIT commands through the windows CMD and verify that the problem is maintained. Has anyone had this inconvenience ?. For what I dedicate when using the GIT bash located in **"C:\ Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"** it uses in some way the windows CMD and this in turn does not correctly display the words with lines. Thank you.

[image: git showing the log correctly]
[image: git with error]
[image: git with error]

Comment: What version of Git are you using? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53345864/6309)

Answer (score 0):

I always used Git bash but for CMD suggestions see [this StackExchange link](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)
which says, you'll need to change your codepage to UTF8 by Opening CMD and run `chcp 65001` and on the CommandPromt properties->Font, change Font to "Lucida Console".