# Git commit history by author name and log output to .txt file

Tags: git, version-control

For audit purposes, I want to run a query across 100+ git repos and identify if certain author has made any commits in the last 2 months. Here is what I have so far.

for i in */.git; do ( echo $i; cd $i/..; git shortlog -sn --all --since=2.months.ago --author="First, Last"; ); done

This loops through a list of repos and gives me a number of commits made by the author. I need help to write this output to text/excel file/sheet? Also, how do I include multiple authors in the same command? 
Can someone guide me on how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When `shortlog` lists you a number of commits from an author what *commit date* do you want?

Comment: Are on linux/windows? there are different ways to generate xls/csv/txt files in different OS

Comment: I am using windows.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can redirect the output of a command  to a file:

```bash
for i in */.git; do 
  echo $i >> res; 
  cd $i/..; 
  git shortlog -sn --all --since=2.months.ago --author="First, Last"; >> res 
done
```

Second, do that with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), as before that, "[`git shortlog -n`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dd7c820d9efef5b8c162fcd56d5e71fc393cd1b0/Documentation/git-shortlog.txt#L29)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#Documentation/git-shortlog.txt--n))</sup> relied on the underlying `qsort()` to be stable, which shouldn't have.
Fixed.

See [commit df534dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df534dcbaafa74be9e922418712bede75676588b) (14 Jul 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dd7c820](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd7c820d9efef5b8c162fcd56d5e71fc393cd1b0), 22 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`shortlog`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df534dcbaafa74be9e922418712bede75676588b): use a stable sort
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> When sorting the output of [`git shortlog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/df534dcbaafa74be9e922418712bede75676588b/Documentation/git-shortlog.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog))</sup> by count, a list of authors in alphabetical order is then sorted by contribution count.
> Obviously, the idea is to maintain the alphabetical order for items with identical contribution count.
>
> At the moment, this job is performed by `qsort()`.
> As that function is not guaranteed to implement a stable sort algorithm, this can lead to inconsistent and/or surprising behavior: items with identical contribution count could lose their alphabetical sub-order.
>
> The `qsort()` in MS Visual C's runtime does *not* implement a stable sort algorithm, and under certain circumstances, that leads to instances where two authors both are listed with 2 contributions, and are listed in inverse alphabetical order.
>
> Let's instead use the stable sort provided by `git_stable_qsort()` to avoid this inconsistency.
>
> This is a companion to [2049b8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2049b8dc65e7371c56452cfda5234182d58b704e) (`diffcore_rename()`: use a stable sort, 2019-09-30, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/772cad0afb834b9af8ee56511dc3df4d6e2f011d) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70bf0b755af4d1e66da25b7805cac0e481a082e4)) `(diffcore_rename()`: use a stable sort, 2019-09-30), [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53345864/6309).