# Utf-8 encoding not working on utf-8 encoded document using php 5.5

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am experiencing a very strange kind of encoding problem i don't really understand and never had before. I am using PHP 5.5 on an Ubuntu machine just for the info.

**To the Problem**

I have a simple file index.php where i want to print this simple string

```
<?php echo "übermotivierter";  ?>
```

When viewing this in the Browser  i would expect following ouput

```
�bermotivierter
```

This works like expected!

To display this in the correct way i have done following steps

1. Changed the encoding of my IDE ( Zend Studio ) to UTF-8 and saved the file again
2. Set the appropriate html meta tag

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   ```
3. Set the appropriate php header

   ```
   <?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
   ```

After doing this i would have expected this to display in a correct way but i am still getting this weired � in the output!

**The workaround**

To make this thing displaying correctly i had to do that

```
<?php echo utf8_encode("übermotivierter");  ?>
```

Now it displays in a correct way.

**My Question**

I really dont understand why i have to use **utf8_encode** when my document already is encoded and saved in utf-8. That doesn't make any sense to me. Any explanation to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer but too long for a comment:

Could you please try

```
<?php
$s = "übermotivierter";
echo '<p>', $s, '</p><p>';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($s); $i++) {
    printf('%02x ', ord($s[$i]));
}
echo '</p>';
```

in the place where you had `<?php echo "übermotivierter";  ?>`?
What's the output of that?

Comment: `�bermotivierter

fc 62 65 72 6d 6f 74 69 76 69 65 72 74 65 72`

Comment: Then I doubt that you've successfully switched the file's encoding to utf-8; it's still iso-8859-1 ;-)

Comment: But IDE is set to UTf-8. Can it be related to GIT checkout ?

Answer (score 4):

With Git 2.18+ (Q2 2018), you might not need any third-party trick to convert a repo content into UTF-8, since the **new "checkout-encoding" attribute** can ask Git to convert the contents to the specified encoding when checking out to the working tree (and the other way around when checking in).

See [commit e92d622](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e92d6225361eba5ff34696122d1491dc7ace2a5a), [commit 541d059](https://github.com/git/git/commit/541d059cd903bb8e510f876ea2bc33719b76b33c), [commit 7a17918](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a17918c34f4e83982456ffe22d880c3cda5384f), [commit 107642f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/107642fe2661236f48b912480e090799e339c512), [commit c6e4865](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6e48652f69f6955bbbb423100e0df2a49467db8), [commit 10ecb82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10ecb82e4f1f507d5f122e00fd4829b30953f853), [commit 2f0c4a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f0c4a362c5db677ee392a6a550632bfb22d8319) (15 Apr 2018), [commit 66b8af3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66b8af3e124a0c9dbad05f40c2f6d27614f34349) (09 Mar 2018), and [commit 13ecb46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13ecb4638ed92a56e855d2e6d3a9b71c4125eb51), [commit a8270b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8270b0980f88a918f9135e02e86ac6143848d95) (15 Feb 2018) by [Lars Schneider (`larsxschneider`)](https://github.com/larsxschneider).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1ac0ce4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ac0ce4d32ab7a3546e7e84a562625576208c7db), 08 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `convert`: add '`working-tree-encoding`' attribute
>
> Git recognizes files encoded with ASCII or one of its supersets (e.g.
>   UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1) as text files.
>   All other encodings are usually interpreted as binary and consequently built-in Git text processing tools (e.g. '`git diff`') as well as most Git web front ends do not visualize the content.
>
> Add an attribute to tell Git what encoding the user has defined for a
>   given file. If the content is added to the index, then Git reencodes
>   the content to a canonical UTF-8 representation. On checkout Git will
>   reverse this operation.

If there is any issue, you now have [the `GIT_TRACE_WORKING_TREE_ENCODING` environment variable](https://github.com/git/git/commit/541d059cd903bb8e510f876ea2bc33719b76b33c) to enable tracing for content that is reencoded with the 'working-tree-encoding' attribute.
This is useful to debug encoding issues.

The [documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/107642fe2661236f48b912480e090799e339c512/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L275-L352) now mentions:

> Please note that using the `working-tree-encoding` attribute may have a
>   number of pitfalls:
>
> - Alternative Git implementations (e.g. JGit or libgit2) and older Git
>     versions (as of March 2018) do not support the `working-tree-encoding`
>     attribute.
>     If you decide to use the `working-tree-encoding` attribute in your repository, then it is strongly recommended to ensure that *all* clients working with the repository support it.
>
>   For example, Microsoft Visual Studio resources files (`*.rc`) or
>     PowerShell script files (`*.ps1`) are sometimes encoded in UTF-16.
>     If you declare `*.ps1` as files as UTF-16 and you add `foo.ps1` with a `working-tree-encoding` enabled Git client, then `foo.ps1` will be stored as UTF-8 internally.
>     A client without `working-tree-encoding` support will checkout `foo.ps1` as UTF-8 encoded file. This will typically cause trouble for the users of this file.
>
>   If a Git client, that does not support the `working-tree-encoding` attribute, adds a new file `bar.ps1`, then `bar.ps1` will be stored "as-is" internally (in this example probably as UTF-16).
>     A client with `working-tree-encoding` support will interpret the internal contents as UTF-8 and try to convert it to UTF-16 on checkout. That operation will fail and cause an error.
> - Reencoding content requires resources that might slow down certain Git operations (e.g '`git checkout`' or '`git add`').
>
> Use the `working-tree-encoding` attribute only if you cannot store a file
>   in UTF-8 encoding and if you want Git to be able to process the content
>   as text.

---

> As an example, use the following attributes if your '`*.ps1`' files are
>   UTF-16 encoded with byte order mark (BOM) and you want Git to perform
>   automatic line ending conversion based on your platform.
>
> ```
> *.ps1     text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16
> ```
>
> Use the following attributes if your '`*.ps1`' files are UTF-16 little
>   endian encoded without BOM and you want Git to use Windows line endings
>   in the working directory.
>   Please note, it is highly recommended to explicitly define the line endings with `eol` if the `working-tree-encoding` attribute is used to avoid ambiguity.
>
> ```
> *.ps1 text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16LE eol=CRLF
> ```