# git checkout branch ends up modifying files

Tags: git

I have a Mac on which I clone a repo. When I checkout any branch, the `.json` files I have end up showing up as "modified".

Here is the list of things I tried.

1. `git clone <blah>.git`
2. `git checkout release`
3. `git checkout -- $(git ls-files -m)`

Files still show as modified:

```
me@box> cat ~/.gitattributes
text=auto
-crlf

me@box> cat .gitconfig
[core]
    autocrlf = true
```

I have tried `autocrlf` with `auto` and `false`, too.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I think you are on the right track, and the problem is the line endings.

Comment: Is it ok to ask git to not do anything related to ELF on the files? Then try adding this to `.git/info/attributes`: `* -text`. That is telling git to use the files as they are on the repo. Can also be set on a .gitattributes file on the working tree.

Comment: Didn't help. Same problem, json files are modified.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

You *may* want `.gitattributes` (not `~/.gitattributes`) to contain the line `* -text` or `*.json -text`.  You *may* want to remove any `autocrlf = true` setting from `.git/config` or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` or `$HOME/.config/git/config` or `$HOME/.gitconfig`.  You might want finer control of additional files, depending on how you and others are using these repositories, on which systems.

## Long

For one thing, these lines are wrong:

> ```
> text=auto
> -crlf
> ```

The entries in `.gitattributes` should have the form of a file name or pattern, followed by white space (typically a tab but blanks are OK too), followed by one or more attributes.  Here, the file name / pattern part is missing, though Git does not see it that way: what this tells Git to do is to apply *no* attributes to all files named `text=auto`, and apply *no* attribute to all files named `-crlf`.  Since there probably are no files with these funny names, this applies no attributes to no files—so it has no effect.

(You probably wanted `* text=auto` and/or `* -crlf`, but see below.)

Similarly (but perhaps not the problem), this *might* be the wrong place:

> ```
> cat ~/.gitattributes
> ```

Git looks for attribute files in several places.  The most important one is `.gitattributes` in the top level of the repository work-tree, i.e., `.gitattributes`, not `~/.gitattributes`.  You *can* have Git consult `core.attributesFile`, which you can set to `~/.gitattributes`.  Modern Git looks for `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/attributes` or `$HOME/.config/git/attributes` if `core.attributesFile` is not set, so unless you configured your global `core.attributesFile` setting, it won't be looking in `$HOME/.gitattributes`.

#### Opinion: `core.autocrlf` is not a good idea

> ```
> cat .gitconfig
> [core]
>     autocrlf = true
> ```

If this was from your home directory, this may be the source of the problem.

Setting `core.autocrlf` to `true` acts this way, as described in [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> Setting this variable to "true" is the same as setting the `text`
>    attribute to "auto" on all files and `core.eol` to "crlf". Set to
>    true if you want to have CRLF line endings in your working
>    directory and the repository has LF line endings. This variable can
>    be set to *input*, in which case no output conversion is performed.

In general, I dislike `text=auto`, because it means Git has to *guess* whether your file is text.  Will Git guess wrong?  Sometimes, yes, it will.  If you are on Linux, where the end-of-line conversion defaults to *do nothing*, this is harmless, but on Windows and MacOS, it's not so harmless.  Here, a `.gitattributes` file listing specifically which line endings go in which files is useful.

It's worth looking at the `core.eol` description as well, since you mentioned setting `core.autocrlf` to `false`:

> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files
>    that have the text property set when `core.autocrlf`is false.
>    Alternatives are *lf*, *crlf* and *native*, which uses the platform’s
>    native line ending. The default value is native. See
>    [gitattributes(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) for more information on end-of-line conversion.
>
> I have tried `autocrlf` with `auto` and `false`, too.

The only valid settings are `true`, `false`, and `input`.  Well, technically, setting it to `1`, `0`, and `-1` respectively also work, as Git will try to convert it as an integer if it does not match one of these words.  Setting it to the literal string `auto` makes Git treat it as an integer, which converts to the value `0`, and hence means `false`.  That's the default, in which case `core.eol` comes into play *provided* there are no overrides in `.gitattributes` files.

Much of the remaining things to know are buried in [that `gitattributes` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html), except for a few key items that are not properly described anywhere.  These require a clear definition of Git's *index* and *work-tree*.

#### Commits, the index, and the work-tree

The first thing to realize is that *any committed file is frozen into whatever data is in the committed form of that file, forever that way in that particular commit*.  That is, each commit holds a snapshot of *every* file—well, every file that's in that commit, but that seems a bit redundant—in the form it had in the index when whoever made the snapshot, made the snapshot (by running `git commit`).

If a committed file has a line that ends with CR-then-LF, followed by a second line that ends with CR-without-LF, followed by a third line that ends with LF-without-CR, that committed version of that file *always* has that form.  There is nothing anyone can do about this.  If you have that commit, you have that file, with those three line endings in that order.  You can choose to check it out, or not; but whatever you do, or don't do, that file exists in that form in that commit.

But wait!  The act of *checking out* some file—or a commit full of files, for that matter—does not mean *put that file into the work-tree as-is*.  Let's consider a file such as `x.json`.  First, the file has to go through your *index*.  Git's index is a special data structure (stored in one big flat file, usually, although there are some optimizations that use more than one file sometimes: the flat file has various index slots, found partly by names like `x.json`, along with linkages to the internal data, which is really stored elsewhere: the index copy is actually just a pointer to the real data).  The index has two more names, reflecting, perhaps, its importance in Git, or perhaps that the name *index* leaves something to be desired: it's also called the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*, depending on who / what part of Git is doing the calling.

In any case, the `x.json` inside the commit is frozen, as we just mentioned, but also is in a special, compressed (sometimes highly compressed) Git-only format.  Git first copies that `x.json` to your index, unfreezing the file, but keeping it in the special Git-only format.  Since the copy in your index currently matches the copy in the commit, it has the same line-endings.  But since it's *not* frozen, you can *change* the line endings, if you like.  Before we get there, let's look at the last step of checking out `x.json`.

The Git-only file is useless to anything other than Git.  So, Git copies the unfrozen, Git-only file from the index to your *work-tree*, creating an actual, ordinary-format, `x.json` file.  It's this last step that does the first pass of end-of-line manipulation, based on:

- whether the file has been detected as "text"—a non-text file is never manipulated this way—and
- the `eol` setting, if there is any, from the `.gitattributes` file or implied by `core.eol` or `core.autocrlf`, more or less in that order.

You can, of course, also copy from the work-tree to the index.  At *this* time, Git will once again do end-of-line manipulation, based on those same two items, plus the `input` setting, which tells Git to do end-of-line conversions even if the *output* pass didn't.

## The conversions

There are actually two possible conversions.  The first, and most common, have to do with carriage-return and line-feed line endings.  The second, which is new since [commit 107642fe2661](https://github.com/git/git/commit/107642fe2661236f48b912480e090799e339c512) (first appearing in Git 2.18.0), has to do with Unicode encodings.

#### CRLF conversions

While copying from index to work-tree, Git will replace LF-only line endings with CRLF line endings if you have told it to do so.  It will not replace CR-LF with LF; it only does LF-to-CRLF here.

While copying from work-tree to index, Git will replace CRLF line endings with LF-only line endings if you have told it to do so.  It will not replace LF with CRLF; it does onyl CRLF-to-LF here.  There is some extra magic in modern Git: if the *index* copy of the file has any carriage-return (`\r` or `^M` characters), Git inhibits conversion unless it's doing a "renormalize" operation (`git add --renormalize`, plus a merge or cherry-pick with the renormalize flag turned on).

#### Unicode conversions

As I mentioned, these were new in Git 2.18 (and are still new to me).  Git will now re-encode UTF-16 files into UTF-8, and vice versa, if you tell it to, through a `.gitattributes` entry.  As with the end of line conversions, these are directional: `git add`, which copies from work-tree to index, prepares the file for storage inside Git and will convert *to* UTF-8, while `git checkout` or `git checkout-index` (or various additional cases like `git reset --hard`), which copies from index to work-tree, will convert *from* UTF-8.

Additional re-encodings may be available, based on whatever `iconv --list` prints.  This, too, is described in [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).

## Changing `text=` and conversion-bypassing issues

The default for Git is to *guess* whether some file is text or not.  If a file *is* text, it gets converted; if not, Git treats it as sacrosanct: whatever is in the index goes into the work-tree, and whatever is in the work-tree goes into the index.  So `* -text` tells Git: *never touch any file at all*, and there are no issues.  But what if Git was previously thinking `* text=auto`?

The answer is to this question is: this does not work well.  Bad things happen!  Except for `git add --renormalize`, Git will *believe* that the index and work-tree match—and hence not bother to copy one way or the other, if the file was recently extracted or added.

That is, in particular, watch out for this:

```
$ git checkout branch
$ echo '* -text' > .gitattributes   # avoid conversions
$ git add file.ext                  # use whatever's in the work-tree
```

and this:

```
$ git checkout branch
$ echo '* -text' > .gitattributes   # avoid conversions
$ git checkout -- file.ext          # see what's actually in the commit
```

The `git add` or `git checkout` step here *may do nothing* on the assumption that the work-tree and index already match, even if they only *used to match based on the previous `.gitattributes` setting* (or lack thereof).  You can force the extraction, or the adding, by modifying (or even removing, if you're going to re-extract) the file, so that the work-tree copy is now clearly different.  But in general, it's annoying and tricky to get a `.gitattributes` change to take effect, because Git doesn't realize that modifying `.gitattributes` can *change the conversions Git will perform*.

For that matter, the same is true of `core.eol` and `core.autocrlf`: changing these configuration items changes the conversion Git might perform, yet Git is not aware that the index and work-tree may now be out of sync with each other.  The index's *cache* aspect works against you here.

Finally, note that Git will tell you that some file is or would be modified if Git sees that `git add`-ing the file *would* change the line endings.  Sometimes Git guesses wrong, especially after altering `.gitattributes` entries so that files that were classified as text are now classified as binary, or vice versa.  In these cases, you have to `git add` the file anyway, so that Git updates the index copy, after which Git realizes that the updated index copy still matches the `HEAD` commit and that the file isn't modified after all.

In other words, sometimes fixing the `.gitattributes` file is not sufficient, *even if the file isn't going to change.*  Note also that sometimes, the *committed version of the file has the wrong line endings* if the `.gitattributes` entry was missing or incorrect.  The work-tree copy may well be right, but until you make a *new* commit that has the frozen copy built from a correct *index* copy, Git will—this time correctly—tell you that the file is modified!

Comment: Regarding the UTF-8 conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50435869/6309

Comment: Thanks torek will try and get back