# View powershell diff in GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, powershell, github, utf-16

I'm using Git as my DVCS with GitHub Desktop as my gui. I'm trying to view the diff of commits of my PS script via GitHub but it treats it as a binary.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145687/why-does-git-think-my-sql-file-is-a-binary-file/28145968#28145968), I have included a .gitattribute file to the root of the repo to diff .ps1 files, `*.ps1 diff`. However, because .ps1 files are UTF-16, it is unsuccessful and doesn't actually diff anything. Is there a way to encode PS files in UTF-8 or are there any other workarounds to this issue?

Comment: `.ps1` scripts should be UTF8 or UTF8 w/ BOM.  If you're running into Unicode (UTF16), you should convert them.

Comment: If you're using VSCode, you can click on the file encoding in the bottom right and then choose "Save With Encoding" and select the proper one(s).

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm running this from the PowerShell ISE included with Windows. Any reason why that would be any different?

Comment: It should be saving files with UTF8 encoding and I haven't observed it behaving any different (except when creating `.psd1` files with `New-ModuleManifest` being UTF16LE).  I would suggest migrating to VSCode with the PS extension as that's Microsoft's stated direction for PowerShell script editing.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I moved to VSCode and can confirm the previous version was in UTF16, I have since converted to UTF8 and diff works great now! Thanks for the help.