# Why does git interpret sql files as binaries during a merge conflict?

Tags: sql, git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I got the problem with resolving merge conflicts within sql files.

```
MenkeTTA@909086 MINGW64 //FILE0019 (master)
$ git pull
remote: Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Services
remote: Found 5 objects to send. (5 ms)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From https://***
d58a69b..4830c58  master     -> origin/master
warning: Cannot merge binary files: example_StoredProcedure.sql (HEAD vs.    4830c5886d3e1eac5ac76d1d49496afb43f444c3)
Auto-merging WRR - example_StoredProcedure.sql
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in example_StoredProcedure.sql 
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

When the merge conflict is created git isn't creating a pre-merged file with the competing changes as in the usual structure:

/SQL-File/

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
competing change A
=======
competing change B
>>>>>>> branch-a
```

Git is treating both files as binaries – but only for the merge-conflict operations (normal merge without conflict works properly). I can choose my own version of the file or the pulled competing file from the remote as the new head for the next push.

I reproduced this conflict with a normal .txt file. Git is treating the merge conflict then as expected with creating one pre-merged file with both competing changes/commits where I can manually fix the code how I want to.

To make git recognize the sql files as text I added

```
.sql diff
```

to the .gitattributes file like it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145687/why-does-git-think-my-sql-file-is-a-binary-file). Does anyone know how I can make git to create a ordinary pre-merged file with both versions of the competing commits when working with sql files?

Comment: I don't think your hypothesis that Git is treating plain text SQL files as binary is correct.  Rather, my guess is that Git is just auto merging, perhaps in a way you disagree with.  While there is a way to force Git to conflict every merge, I would first look to your Git workflow, and try to separate concerns better.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I added the original output from the git client to the post to give more insight regarding my git workflow. Git is aborting auto-merging and interprets the sql file as binary. When I checked the the file afterwards I just found my previous changes.

Answer (score 1):

First, a quick note:

> To make git recognize the sql files as text I added
>
> ```
> .sql diff
> ```
>
> to the .gitattributes file ...

The `.gitattributes` line should read `*.sql diff` (I've fixed the linked answer, which is on a question about getting `git diff` to treat the file as text).  However, if the file really *is* text, you may want, or even need, `*.sql text`.  **Note: this will not help at all if the file is *not* text.  If the file's content is UTF-16, it is not text to Git, at least.**

Consider marking the file as `example_StoredProcedure.sql text`, i.e., not *all* `.sql` files, just this *one particular* file.  <s>I'm also curious to see whether just marking it `diff` suffices!</s>  Update, Nov 2019: apparently marking the file as `diff` is not sufficient, though I have not verified this myself.

(The difference is that the `diff` attribute tells Git how to show the file in `git diff` output,<sup>1</sup> while the `text` tells Git that instead of using its built in guessing algorithm, it should, for *all* purposes, use the setting to decide whether the file is text.  The guessing algorithm consists of scanning an initial chunk of the file's contents to see how many "text-like" characters there are vs "non-text-like" characters.  Probably there should be a special allowance for UTF-8 Byte Order Markers at the top, but [there isn't](https://github.com/git/git/blob/29d9e3e2c47dd4b5053b0a98c891878d398463e3/convert.c#L38-L104).  Curiously, during filtering, [there are explicit checks](https://github.com/git/git/blob/29d9e3e2c47dd4b5053b0a98c891878d398463e3/convert.c#L270-L326).)

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, it's actually more involved than just *showing*, but I think this is a good way to start thinking about the issues.  Note that you can augment the `diff` setting with a *driver*.  It's not clear to me how the low level file merge interacts with a diff driver and I do not have time to experiment with it right now.

---

#### Longer explanation

> ```
> warning: Cannot merge binary files: example_StoredProcedure.sql (... vs ...)
> ```

tells us that you are correct, that Git is treating the three versions of `example_StoredProcedure.sql` as binary.  (I see you added this output after the initial question; good thing, since it's the key!)

But why did I say *three* versions, when the line goes on to say:

> ```
> HEAD vs.    4830c5886d3e1eac5ac76d1d49496afb43f444c3
> ```

Git is being a little lazy here: all merges involve three inputs, not just two.  One of these is the one you supply explicitly—or, as in this case, `git pull` ran `git merge` and *`git pull` itself* supplied the big ugly hash ID `4830c5886d3e1eac5ac76d1d49496afb43f444c3`.

The second input to a merge is always the *current commit*, aka `HEAD`.  You normally get this by being on the branch in the first place: `HEAD` names the branch-name, the branch-name identifies the commit, and this is where you want the final merge commit to go, so it all fits together.

The third input—or internally, *first*; internally the "theirs" version is the third input—is one that Git computes *for* you, based on the `HEAD` and other or `--theirs` commits: Git walks through enough of the commit graph to find the best common ancestor commit.<sup>1</sup>  It's this common ancestor commit that determines *which files need merging*, and if a file does need merging, the built in merge driver needs to use diffs to get textual changes to merge.  For both this and for `git diff`, Git has a [differencing engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_differencing) built in to it (modified from [LibXDiff](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/LibXDiff)).

Hence Git can, in effect, run:

```
git diff --find-renames <merge base commit> HEAD
```

to see what we did to each of our files, and:

```
git diff --find-renames <merge base commit> <other commit>
```

to see what they did to each of our files.  Then:

- If we changed a file and they did not touch it at all, the merge is easy: *take ours.*
- If they changed a file and we did not touch it at all, the merge is easy: *take theirs.*
- If we both changed a file but made the new file exactly the same, the merge is easy: *take either one (ours, really, since it's in place).*
- Otherwise, *attempt to combine the changes*.

For speed reasons, Git uses the hash IDs ("blob" hashes, for the file's content) to accomplish the first three bullet points without ever having to fire up the file-level diff.  This can, and does, merge unconflicted binary-file changes.  It's only the final stage, where all three blob hashes differ, that requires a textual diff so as to combine changes.

Obviously, if Git can't diff the file, it cannot merge the two diff outputs.  But does just marking the file as text-diff-able (`pattern diff` in `.gitattributes`) make the merge proceed?  What happens if you set a diff *driver*, does the low-level file merge code use that driver?  It "wants" to use the xdiff internal interface to find hunks; that's a lot easier than interpreting text output from a driver; you probably have to define a *merge driver* to get a detected-as-binary file to be merged, even if you have marked it as `diff`.

**Additional note, Nov 2019:** Since Git 2.18, Git has the ability to convert between committed UTF-8 data and in-work-tree other-format data.  To use this, set the `working-tree-encoding` attribute.  For instance, [the gitattributes documentation] shows an example line:

```
*.ps1    text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16LE eol=CRLF
```

that would keep all `*.ps1` files in UTF-8 internally (in the frozen, committed files inside each commit) but keep the useful-format versions of those files in your work-tree in UTF-16-LE.  **I have no data as to whether this would work with these SQL files.**

---

<sup>1</sup>In all cases, but especially in problem cases where there's more than one best common ancestor, `git merge`'s behavior actually depends on the *strategy* you chose.  The usual `recursive` strategy will merge the merge bases, commit the result, and then use that commit as the merge base!  Other merge strategies work differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that really instructive reply. Regarding the entry in the .gitattributes file I did a typo in the original post. I inserted `*.sql diff` how it should be. I also already tried the version with `*.sql text` unfortunately it led to the same conflict. Could you please describe what you mean with "set a diff driver "? Do you know how I could define a **merge driver** for this specific case?

Comment: You mean that with `*.sql text`, you still got the "warning: Cannot merge binary files" complaint? As for defining a merge driver, that's straightforward enough mechanically: see [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver). However, writing the actual *driver* is hard.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Unfortunately `*.sql text ` didn't help. I also tried now the `example_StoredProcedure.sql text` option but it didn't help. I can't believe that it's so hard to fix the issue. There have to be quite a lot of people who are using git versioning for sql files.

Comment: This is well outside of the range of things I normally do, but I imagine the way to merge sql files is to dump them to text, merge the text, and then build a new sql file from the result. (That's something you can do in a merge driver.) Google turned this up, though it's specifically aimed at sqlite: https://github.com/cannadayr/git-sqlite

Comment: @Riz: it's not clear what you mean by "this". Is the file *actually* text, or is it actually binary? Did you define and write your own merge driver, and that still doesn't work? (Note that Git won't invoke a merge driver unless all *three* inputs are different.)

Comment: SQL files generated by a Microsoft tool (and there's a hint about this in the question) may well be stored in UTF-16 encoding. That may well explain the "binary mystery".

Comment: @torek by "this" i mean your solution doesn't work for me. Since the question is about .sql files being misinterpreted as binary, yes it is text.

Comment: @Riz: Ah. Note that my answer was mainly about the fact that `.sql diff` is wrong, it's `*.sql` or `somefile.sql` and `text`: `diff` just marks the file as text-ish for diff purposes, not more generally (e.g., for CRLF editing). But if the file is genuinely binary—as UTF-16 in fact is (and see kostix comment)—`git merge` will not be able to merge it without assistance, e.g., from a merge driver.