# SQL files stored as Bin in local Git repository

Tags: git

In a local Git repository for a project, when the `git log --stat` command is issued, the following is a sample of lines that are outputted:

[image]

The last 2 lines look normal but why do the first 2 lines show `Bin 0 -> ___ bytes`?  Those 2 files were scripted out of a MS SQL Server database using SQL Server Management Studio and consist of `INSERT` statements to populate database tables with data.  They are both around 1,950 lines long, if that matters.  Also, this is on a Windows 10 machine.  I would've expected them to be handled the same way as other .sql files (like the last 2 on the list).

Comment: Are they newly-added in this commit?

Comment: Yes they were added in this commit.

Comment: It seems the newly-added sql files are considered as binaries and the original ones as text files. Run `file Data/Data_AsScriptedFromDB_2015-03-10.sql` and `file Scripts/2013-11-24_script2_AlterTables.sql` to check if the outputs are the same.

Comment: Did you define some of the sql files, whose names match a certain pattern, as text files in `.gitattributes`?

Answer (score 0):

Using Notepad++ it was possible to see that the 2 files being treated as binary files were encoded as `UCS-2 LE BOM`:

[image]

For each file, choosing the `Convert to UTF-8` option and then saving the file allowed Git to recognize the files as text files.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145687/why-does-git-think-my-sql-file-is-a-binary-file) was a useful thread to figure out this issue.