# Making git diff (NOT difftool) and git log -p work with *.sql files and Windows PowerShell

Tags: git, unicode, sql-scripts, git-diff

I know how to configure an external tool to view differences with a call to `git difftool`.  However, if I want to see an 'dump' of all changes for entire history of a file to my console window, I wanted to use `git log -p <filename>`.  The problem I'm having is with *.sql files in my Windows environment.  `difftool` (using my my configured tool) correctly handles the unicode file, however `diff` does not, which is what I **think** `git log -p` uses under the hood.

Is there a way to make `git diff` 'work' with files of a given/configured extension where I know there is truly only ANSI characters and show actual text changes outputted to the console (in my case Windows PowerShell hosted inside Console).

Note: I've looked at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text/778156#778156) about making git diff recognize UTF16, but I couldn't get it to work (both iconv and mktemp were not present on my system).

Maybe this is the approach I should continue to examine/experiment with as the only possible solution?  Or is my only solution is to ensure files where I know only ANSI characters are present are saved as ANSI - would be disappointing to lose all the history I currently have on *.sql files (and any other files I'm not aware of that are stored as unicode right now - I'm a newly converted git user from Visual SourceSafe, so haven't had to view differences on all my file types that I modify yet).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at git attributes. You can customize how certain files are handled by diff and other aspects.

How this helps

Comment: So I've added a .gitattributes file with `*.sql diff=strings`.  Then I downloaded Strings.exe from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439).  Then I added the following to my .gitconfig:


`[diff "strings"]
  textconv = "C:/BTR/PowerToys/SysInternals/strings.exe"
  cachetextconv = true`

Yet, when I do a git diff on a *.sql file, I get:

`diff --git a/path/to/*.sql b/path/to/*.sql
index <sha>..<sha> 100644
Binary files a/path/to/*.sql and b/path/to/*.sql differ`

Any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to notify you with @...I assume I need to do that for you to get an email?  Wish I could get line feeds in my previous comment :(  Hopefully you can decipher what I wrote.