# Why git decide that my file is binary

Tags: git

I have added plain text file to the repository and git decided that it is a binary file. 
Here is my file ([link](https://github.com/demas/reporting-server/blob/master/warehouse/warehouse.sql)) and github show it as plain text file.

But if I try to look at [changes which have been made by last commit](https://github.com/demas/reporting-server/commit/aade4c659bd86346e16ec2f0ad24890db7c2d63c) I see the message

```
Binary file not shown
```

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you do a git log -p locally? This might just be a github bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From cloning your repo, I see that the file in question is UTF-16. I don't believe git supports this as a text format. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/777949/576139) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

It is encoded in UTF-16. Try changing the encoding to ASCII or UTF-8 and commit and push.