# How do I make git-lfs treat a file as binary?

Tags: git, attributes, git-lfs

It's possible to make git [treat a file as binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162267/how-do-i-make-git-treat-a-file-as-binary), to avoid attempts to merge and avoid corruption of line endings etc.

I've attempted to do the same with git-lfs, and opened the .gitattributes file to find that git-lfs (already in use in the repo) has added the following attributes:

```
*.mat filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

The link above suggests that I add the binary attribute, which is equivalent to:

```
*.mat -diff -merge -text
```

I *think* it's most likely that this is what I'm looking for:

```
*.mat filter=lfs -diff -merge -text
```

Which I believe should store the file at the git-lfs endpoint and maintain the relevant pointers, but treat it in exactly the same way git would treat a file with the -diff -merge -text attributes.

I'd normally just try this, but am worried about corrupting binaries... so my three-part question is:

1. Is this safe to try?
2. Is this correct?
3. Is there any documentation beyond that on [git attributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) that's specific to git-lfs attributes, and if so where?

Thanks in advance!

Tom

Comment: *"is it safe to try?"* sure, just clone the repository to a new local, then test anything you want in that sandbox. Just don't push until you're sure it's what you want.

Comment: thanks Jeff, I'll have a play.