# Git thinks .ini saved in unicode files are binary

Tags: git

I have a few rainmeter configuration files and I have a few unicode symbols, so I have to `save as`>`unicode` in notepad otherwise it messes up my unicode symbols.

But git thinks that those are binary files and `git-gui` doesn't show me the `diff`.

Is that how it's going to be? or is there a fix for it?

Comment: gitattributes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/778167/1031417

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I make git recognize a UTF-16 file as text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.gitattributes` file with the contents

```
pattern diff
```

where `pattern` is a pattern that matches the names of the configuration files. This will make diff treat the files as text.

The [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) has a [chapter on Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes), and there's the [man page](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.html) of course.