# git creates lots of cryptic files

Tags: git, file, pack

Lately, Git started to create lots of cryptic files in the root directory of my local Git repo. IntelliJ shows these files with names like this "w遼矓w䬨+"

Git bash shows these files with names like this "???w?????????w?????+"

Each of them has hundreds of lines which all look like this ".git/objects/pack/pack-d9b8a9c4b483e7ff2551826b82f7876a175ef3dc.pack 1132"

I can delete as many of them as a want. They keep being recreated again.

How can I get rid of these?

Comment: `git` itself should not create those, it should be some other software, maybe some script went mad or something. Can you see any meaning for the numbers related to the pack files?

Comment: Could be related to this file encoding issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515768/git-messed-up-my-files-showing-chinese-characters-in-some-places. Either IntelliJ or Git messed it up these files. 
Which version of git are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the git version upgrade solved my problem.

I did use the git version 1.8.5
After upgrading git to version 2.16.2 git stopped to create these files.