# How to see the differnce in git diff?

Tags: git

I WROTE THIS

git diff B.txt

OUTPUT

diff --git a/B.txt b/B.txt
index 3bcc974..7be6bf0 100644
Binary files a/B.txt and b/B.txt differ

BUT ME  i want to see the content  about the  changes could help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make git recognize a UTF-16 file as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836968/why-does-git-treat-this-text-file-as-binary-and-fail-to-provide-meaningful-diff

Comment: @mike maybe also random capitalization, typos, no format, no ponctuation, and approximative grammar?

Answer (score 2):

Git has identified that file as binary files rather than text, probably because it contains some unexpected control characters. You can use the `-a` (`--text`) option to `git diff` to force `git` to treat the files as text:

```
git diff -a B.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Git has looked in the file `B.txt` and decided that it is not a text file, but a "binary file". This could be because it contains a character that is not "text", or perhaps it has very long lines.

Git has to guess if the file is text or not (it can't tell by looking at the `.txt` in its name). For binary files (such as image files), git will just print a message to say if the file is the same or different, rather than show you the differences.

Probably `B.txt` has an extended character that is not in ASCII or UTF-8.

You can tell `git` that this is in fact a text file by creating a file named `.gitattributes` (this file's name must start with a period) in your project's main directory, with following content:

```
*.txt diff
```

Then typing `git diff B.txt` should print the actual difference out, because git will treat files ending in `.txt` as files that can be `diff`erenced, no matter what they actually contain.

I suspect you might be using non-UTF8 for most of your files, so that you will need to add other file extensions to this list. Here's an example:

```
*.java diff
*.js diff
*.pl diff
*.txt diff
*.ts diff
*.html diff
*.sh diff
*.xml diff
```