# Character encoding of Localizable.strings, generated by genstrings

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, character-encoding, genstrings

In my "ViewController.swift", I have a localized string:

```
TheOutLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("hello", comment: "The \"hello\" word")
```

In the Terminal, to generate the "Localizable.strings" file, I typed:

```
cd Base.lproj/; genstrings ../*.swift; cat Localizable.strings
```

and got the following result:

```
??/* The \"hello\" word */
"hello" = "hello";
```

When typing `od -c Localizable.strings`, I get:

```
0000000  377 376   /  \0   *  \0      \0   T  \0   h  \0   e  \0      \0
0000020    \  \0   "  \0   h  \0   e  \0   l  \0   l  \0   o  \0   \  \0
0000040    "  \0      \0   w  \0   o  \0   r  \0   d  \0      \0   *  \0
0000060    /  \0  \n  \0   "  \0   h  \0   e  \0   l  \0   l  \0   o  \0
0000100    "  \0      \0   =  \0      \0   "  \0   h  \0   e  \0   l  \0
0000120    l  \0   o  \0   "  \0   ;  \0  \n  \0  \n  \0
```

When I type `file Localizable.strings`, it says:

```
Localizable.strings: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode c program text
```

When I open the file with "emacs", it does not display these characters, and when I type `M-x describe-current-coding-system RET`, it says:

```
Coding system for saving this buffer:
  U -- utf-16le-with-signature-unix (alias: utf-16-le-unix)
```

So, it seems that these octal characters \377 and \376 at the beginning of the file look like kind of a utf-16-le BOM, which explains why each character is followed by a \0 (UTF-16 is twice bigger than UTF-8 in this case).

Is this normal/useful/harmful?

Also, the standard *nix tools (`grep`, `sed`, `awk`) don't handle nicely utf-16 files:

```
grep '=' Localizable.strings 
Binary file Localizable.strings matches

grep -a '=' Localizable.strings | sed -e 's/ = //'
"hello" = "hello";
```

Also, I edited Localizable.strings to replace `"hello";` by `"Hello";`. Then "SourceTree" (my "git" client) is unable to display the difference unless I do, as proposed in [Can I make git recognize a UTF-16 file as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020607/3458802):

```
echo '*.strings diff=localizablestrings' > .../.git/../.gitattributes
echo '[diff "localizablestrings"]' >> .../.git/config
echo '  textconv = "iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8"' >> .../.git/config
```

Apple's [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH19-SW1) says:

> Note: If Xcode warns you that the Localizable.strings file appears to
>   be Unicode (UtF-16), you can convert it to Unicode (UTF-8) using the
>   File inspector.

So, should I remove / ignore the BOM?

It seems there is no `genstrings` option to generate an UTF-8 file.

Should I convert the file?

Comment: Yes, that is a UTF-16 encoded file with BOM, and according to http://www.stevestreeting.com/2010/05/18/os-x-localisation-incremental-genstrings-and-utf-8-files/ and other resources, genstrings has no option to alter this. Xcode can handle that without problems. If you need to work with other tools then you can convert it to UTF-8 (e.g. in the File Inspector in Xcode).

Answer (score 1):

The `genstrings` tool is hard-coded to output strings files in the encoding "UTF-16LE with BOM". I prefer to keep my strings files in UTF-8 and I use the following shell script to generate them:

```zsh
#!/bin/zsh
function convert {
    for file in $@; do
        print "Converting $file to UTF-8"
        iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 $file > temp   
        rm $file; mv temp $file
    done
}
genstrings -o en.lproj *.m
convert en.lproj/*.strings
```

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for the useful answer ! 


Just in case any file name may contain special characters (space tab return), it's safer to _always_ enclose the variables within quotes:


`for file in "$@"; do iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 "$file" > temp; rm "$file"; mv temp "$file"; done`

Comment: That would be the case if running this as a bash script. However being zsh, the paths do not need quoting since zsh variables do not split on whitespace. Appreciate the comment though.