# Xcode archive error: detected encoding of input file as Unicode (UTF-8)

Tags: ios, xcode

The following error occurred when performing iOS app archive:

```
/Users/enix/source/apple/xxx-iOS/xxxxxx/fr.lproj/Localizable.strings:1:1: note: detected encoding of input file as Unicode (UTF-8) (in target 'xxxx' from project 'xxx')

/Users/enix/source/apple/xxx-iOS/xxxxxx/fr.lproj/Localizable.strings:1:1: error: validation failed: Couldn't parse property list because the input data was in an invalid format (in target 'xxxx' from project 'xxxxxxx')
```

I had tried with iconv to convert the localized string to UTF-8 and UTF-16, but still not work.

So, my question is what file encoding format does XCode expect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Character encoding of Localizable.strings, generated by genstrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542388/character-encoding-of-localizable-strings-generated-by-genstrings)

Comment: thanks Jeshua, I have read this post, and had tried with `iconv`, but with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking this question in apple forum, I got the answer finnally:

> This is controlled by the Text Settings pane within in the File inspector. > Select the .strings file on the left and choose View > Inspectors > File.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713382?page=1#725798022