# git status shows no updates but pull brings down changes

Tags: git

I ran a 'git status' on a folder and it replied:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

However, running a git log failed to show the latest update that I know is there:

```
* e2f5a0b (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) First version of all
* f11f989 Initial commit
```

so I ran 'git pull' and it brought down all updates:

```
* 057c274 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) update for ginger
* e2f5a0b First version of all
* f11f989 Initial commit
```

Have I failed to understand something with git? Is it because Git status only works on the current folder - all my updates were in a sub-directory?

Note, the only thing I can see and this might just be a red-herring, is when I look on the web server (I'm using gitlab) I can see the update but on trying to view file history it tells me all the files that have changed but fails to show a diff on them (I did read diff has issues with utf16 but that wouldn't explain this fault?)

thanks for any help.

[EDIT]Note, when I look in the history, it says 'binary files differ', but these are all .SQL text files saved simply by ssms.

Answer (score 5):

`status` shows the status of your local repository. It does not communicate with your remote.

`pull` performs two actions. First `fetch`, which contacts the remote to download new content: that's where the new commit comes from. Then `merge`, which is irrelevant here.

Bottom line: `git fetch` before any remote-related query.

Comment: ah, sorry, I thought somehow it might check the server ;)

maybe I should delete this question and ask another regarding thinking my sql is binary?

Comment: @NeilWalker I'm pretty sure that's a solved problem already, a quick search brought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text) up which seems relevant.

Comment: thanks. It's gitlab showing this issue too as well as 'git for windows gui' and cygwin. I wonder if there's a way to get ssms to conver to utf8...

Comment: the problem is ssms is saving as utf8, but when you script as, it saves as utf16