# git extention treat xml as binary file, and can not see diff info

Tags: git

I am using git extentions as my git client, an in the repository， there is a .xml file, but in the git extentions tool, I cannot see the xml diff, because it has been treated as a binary file, what can I do to see the diffs

[git diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnquv.png)

I have created a .gitattributes file, and write *.xml text, but it seems no use

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbq45.png)

Comment: What's the encoding on that file? You may need to check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text)

Comment: You can try `git diff -a` or `git diff --text`.